# CSS only drop down menu - CSS3 transition

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design, css-transitions

Im creating a drop down menu. Pretty simple works well on a desktop. I need to use the same markup for responsive too. Imagine the menu appears when a user clicks a menu-icon, then simply all the list items are stacked underneath each other.

When the user hovers over 'menu item 1' then the 'sub-menu- appears. At the moment I simply have it to appear and disappear on hover. It doesn't look very nice. I was wondering if there was a simple way to use a CSS3 transition to make this drop down nicely.

Thanks

---

CSS

```
.sub-menu{
 display:none;
}

li.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
 display: block;
}
```

HTML

```
 <nav>
   <ul>
     <li class="sub-menu-parent"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Sub Item 4</a></li>
       </ul>
     </li></ul>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Look into CSS transitions. Also, there is no "hover" state on Mobile phones as we tap with our fingers - unless you're using a Samsung Galaxy Note or another device which allows hovering.

Comment: I'm sure a tap on a phone equates to a hover on a computer.

Comment: A tab on a phone *may* equate a hover, but don't depend on it. It is clumsy, and does not work when you're tapping on a link (like in your code example).

Comment: The countless times I have browsed on a mobile site trying to get into sub-navigation pages and ended up elsewhere because of the hover issue, it's worth considering. Clothing websites seem to be the worst and any other non-optimised websites with Drop-Down menus. You could emulate a "tapped" state by using checkboxes to store a "tapped" state and then use the `:checked` css selector in the same fashion as `:hover`. For an example of this checkbox method, look at my pure CSS accordian: http://jsfiddle.net/EumGj/2/

Answer (score 6):

You will need to use a way of hiding it that doesn't use `display: none` if you want to do a smooth transition. Browsers cannot transition from `none` to `block`, so it's an instant toggle.

One way to hide the `.sub-menu` is to use `visibility: hidden;` then `visibility: visible;` on the hover state, however this makes the transitioning a little more difficult. If you just `transition: all 0.5 ease`, then the menu will fade in smoothly but quickly disappear whenever it loses the :hover.

There's a [full article](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337) that runs through doing this, but the gist is adding a `transition-delay` to visibility, then removing that `transition-delay` on the hover state.

```
.sub-menu-parent { position: relative; }

.sub-menu { 
  visibility: hidden; /* hides sub-menu */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -10%;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.5s; /* the last value is the transition-delay for visibility */
}

.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible; /* shows sub-menu */
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  transition-delay: 0s; /* this removes the transition delay so the menu will be visible while the other styles transition */
}
```

**DEMO:** http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch

Answer (score 1):

This is really useful for nice navigations, especially sub level navs appearing on hover etc

http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/